# Problem with running python code on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here][1]

Hello there,
I am facing the problem you can see in the image.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjV9Z.png

I have python installed in the D directory and added to path, everything looks like it should work.
I am creating a virtual environment for every project I am working on and I don't have any problems running commands like "pip install numpy" but when I try to run my code, even trying to import libraries it fails and the output in the picture is not very significant to me.
Has anyone faced a similar problem? can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You missed a colon after the closing parenthesis of the loop.

Comment: don't name your project files as external modules you want to use, `numpy.py`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging from your screenshot, you have a file named `numpy.py` somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH`, causing Python to import that particular file instead of the NumPy library you intended.

See this link for more information on how Python import works: https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/sys_path.html

Comment: The exact filename is `D:\Python\numpy.py`

Comment: This helped me a lot, I don't know why because I recently reinstalled python in a new partition but this file numpy.py went into tha pythonpath, I didn't noticed it. Thanks!